# SEO при редизайне

Tags: seo, дизайн

Что нужно учитывать при редизайне сайта, чтобы не потерять индексацию поисковиками?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [SEO Website Redesign Checklist: Don’t Mess Up Your Site Traffic](http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/seo-website-redesign-checklist).
- [6 Website Redesign SEO Secrets Your Developer May Not Know](http://www.highrankings.com/6-seo-redesign-secrets).
- [3 SEO Traps to Avoid During Your Redesign](http://www.highrankings.com/seo-redesign-traps-297).

Comment: Последние 2 битые, а первую прочту) 
Спс

Comment: не битые...